# How does the robot Adam match Max's movements when they first find him?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, real-steel

In the movie Real Steel, Charlie Kenton (Hugh Jackman) finds a robot which is badly damaged. Max (Dakota Goya) had a word with the machine and the machine responded. Later on the Charlie says that it mimics human actions.

- Then how did Adam (the Atom boxing robot) respond to Max in the beginning of their interactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Real Steel, the robot dubbed Adam was created with a "shadow function" allowing it to mimic movements it sees. This would allow it to be used as a training partner. It's armored chassis allowed it to sustain massive damage and continue to function. There may have been a voice-activated command function.

> Atom is an obsolete Generation-2 sparring bot from 2014. Atom was designed to sustain massive damage. Atom also has a "shadow function" which allows him to follow or copy human movement. **Wikipedida -> [Real Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Steel)**

*Shows the "shadow function" in action.*